# python win32api blocking bottle routes

Tags: python, winapi, bottle

I have a bottle web application. At some point, i want the server to raise a dialog window to ask the server admin for something. This alert, even when started from a `Thread` is blocking - And i don't really understand why.

To see if this ctypes MessageBox is blocking, i've tried to run it on a thread on a minimal example. I've tried this example:

```
import threading
from threading import Thread
import ctypes
import time
MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA

def alert():
    userChoice = MessageBox(0, "And this is crazy", "Hey I just met you",4)
    threading.Timer(3.0,alert).start()

worker = Thread(target=alert)
worker.setDaemon(False)
worker.start()

while (True):
    print("main thread is printing")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Here, the main thread keeps on printing on 2 seconds interval. Concurrently, each 3 seconds the alert method started from a thread is shown. We clearly see that the loop isn't waiting for the dialog to return a value.

Despite this test, when trying similar code from a bottle application, until 'Yes' or 'No' is clicked on the dialog, the server does not respond to it's routes. Instead, it waits for the dialog to return a value, which means the dialog is blocking execution at some level.

Anyone knows how to raise a dialog without interfering with bottle work? I'm running out of ideas. Appreciate your time and effort.

**UPDATE:**
This isn't the problem. Bottle does run with this example with out interference. The actual issue is better described here: [bottle gevent and threading: gevent is only usable from a single thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517796/bottle-gevent-and-threading-gevent-is-only-usable-from-a-single-thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably use Gevent with your bottle application . If you monkey.patch_all() , your threads become serial , and will block bottle execution .

You should not patch your threads :

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all(thread=False)
```

Comment: This raises another problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517796/bottle-gevent-and-threading-gevent-is-only-usable-from-a-single-thread